# how to get parent div by using children div in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

in this i want div1 as answer...with the children divTab1Btn

am using

```
$('#divTab1Btn').closest().attr("id");
```

But am getting undefined ? what is the correct solution ?

```
<div id="div1">
    <div id="divTab1Heading" style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246);">
        <table style="width: 1024px; height: 40px;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" style="width: 911px; float: left;">
                        <div disabled="disabled" class="tabBtn" id="divTab1Btn" style="display: block; visibility: visible;">
                            <input class="btneditclick" id="divTab1BtnEdit" style="width: 75px; display: block; visibility: visible;" type="button" value="Edit" table2focus="tblAddtype" classvalue="1">
                            <input class="btnconfirm" id="divTab1BtnConfirm" style="width: 85px; display: none; visibility: hidden;" type="button" value="Confirm" classvalue="1" hdnheadergridlinkfield="ADD_MRECID" gridid="1655">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The closest() method requires a selector to find the target element, else it will return an empty object that is the reason for the undefined value.

In your case since there are no other selector to find the parent, I think you can do something like get the `table` and then get the ID of its parent's parent.

```
$('#divTab1Btn').closest('table').parent().parent().attr("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.parents()` to get all the parents and `.last()` will select the last parent element in all divs.

```
var id=$('#divTab1Btn').parents('div').last().prop("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parent()`:

```
var obj = $("#divTab1Btn").parent();
```

Now you have object of parent div and you can use .attr() function to get attribute of parent div.

Example:

```
var obj = $("#divTab1Btn").parent();
var parentId = $(obj).attr("id");
```